# Python 3.2: How do I change from having 2 working classes to only having 1 working class but have Enemy + Player work off of 1 working class?

Tags: python-3.x

> ```
>     **import pygame**
> ```
>
> ***## My problem is from class Player(): to class Enemy()***:
>
> ```
>     **SCR_WID, SCR_HEI = 640, 480**
>     **class Player()**:
>             ***def __init__(self):***
>                     *self.x, self.y = 16, SCR_HEI/2
>                     self.speed = 3
>                     self.padWid, self.padHei = 8, 64
>                     self.score = 0
>                     self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font("imagine_font.ttf", 64)*
>
>             ***def scoring(self):***
>                     *scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
>                     screen.blit(scoreBlit, (32, 16))
>                     if self.score == 10:
>                             print ("player 1 wins!")
>                             exit()
>
>             def movement(self):
>                     keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
>                     if keys[pygame.K_w]:
>                             self.y -= self.speed
>                     elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
>                             self.y += self.speed
>
>                     if self.y <= 0:
>                             self.y = 0
>                     elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-64:
>                             self.y = SCR_HEI-64*
>
>             ***def draw(self):***
>                     *pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, self.padWid, self.padHei))*
>
>     **class Enemy():**
>             ***def __init__(self):***
>                     *self.x, self.y = SCR_WID-16, SCR_HEI/2
>                     self.speed = 3
>                     self.padWid, self.padHei = 8, 64
>                     self.score = 0
>                     self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font("imagine_font.ttf", 64)*
>
>             ***def scoring(self):***
>                     *scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (255, 255, 255))*
>                     *screen.blit(scoreBlit, (SCR_HEI+92, 16))
>                     if self.score == 10:
>                             print ("Player 2 wins!")
>                             exit()*
>
>             ***def movement(self):***
>                     *keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
>                     if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
>                             self.y -= self.speed
>                     elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
>                             self.y += self.speed
>
>                     if self.y <= 0:
>                             self.y = 0
>                     elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-64:
>                             self.y = SCR_HEI-64*
>
>             ***def draw(self):***
>                     *pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, self.padWid, self.padHei))*
>
>     **class Ball():**
>             ***def __init__(self):***
>                     *self.x, self.y = SCR_WID/2, SCR_HEI/2
>                     self.speed_x = -3
>                     self.speed_y = 3
>                     self.size = 8*
>
>             ***def movement(self):***
>                     *self.x += self.speed_x
>                     self.y += self.speed_y
>
>                     #wall col
>                     if self.y <= 0:
>                             self.speed_y *= -1
>                     elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-self.size:
>                             self.speed_y *= -1
>
>                     if self.x <= 0:
>                             self.__init__()
>                             enemy.score += 1
>                     elif self.x >= SCR_WID-self.size:
>                             self.__init__()
>                             self.speed_x = 3
>                             player.score += 1
>                     ##wall col
>                     #paddle col
>                     #player
>                     for n in range(-self.size, player.padHei):
>                             if self.y == player.y + n:
>                                     if self.x <= player.x + player.padWid:
>                                             self.speed_x *= -1
>                                             break
>                             n += 1
>                     #enemy
>                     for n in range(-self.size, enemy.padHei):
>                             if self.y == enemy.y + n:
>                                     if self.x >= enemy.x - enemy.padWid:
>                                             self.speed_x *= -1
>                                             break
>                             n += 1
>                     ##paddle col*
>
>             ***def draw(self):***
>                     *pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, 8, 8))
>
>     SCR_WID, SCR_HEI = 640, 480
>     screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCR_WID, SCR_HEI))
>     pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
>     pygame.font.init()
>     clock = pygame.time.Clock()
>     FPS = 60
>
>     player = Player() 
>     ball = Ball()
>     #player = Player()
>     enemy = Enemy()
>
>     while True:
>             #process
>             for event in pygame.event.get():
>                             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>                                     print ("Game exited by user")
>                                     exit()
>             ##process
>             #logic
>             ball.movement()
>             player.movement()
>             enemy.movement()
>             ##logic
>             #draw
>             screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
>             ball.draw()
>             player.draw()
>             player.scoring()
>             enemy.draw()
>             enemy.scoring()
>             ##draw
>             #_______
>             pygame.display.flip()
>             clock.tick(FPS)*
> ```
>
> ***## My College Professor expects me to do this even though he has never taught the class how to do it. So how am I suppose to do this when I dont know how to do it?!***

Comment: Why all the `***`s? This does not so much seem a legitimate programming question as a request to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code for Player and Enemy, you can see that they're very similar - the only differences between them are:

- x position for the paddle
- x position for the score
- the name for the win messages
- the up and down keys

You could pass these into the `__init__` method and store them as attributes, then use them in the methods that need them.

```
def __init__(self, name, paddleX, scoreX, upKey, downKey):
    self.name = name
    self.paddleX = paddleX
    self.scoreX = scoreX
    self.upKey = upKey
    self.downKey = downKey
    ...
```

Then in the `Player` code you use those instead of the constants the code uses now - so instead of `pygame.K_UP` or `pygame.K_w` you'd use `self.upKey`.

And then instead of:

```
player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()
```

You can pass in the right values for player and enemy:

```
player = Player(
    name='player 1',
    paddleX=16,
    scoreX=16,
    upKey=pygame.K_w,
    downKey=pygame.K_s,
)
enemy = Player(
    name='player 2',
    paddleX=SCR_WID - 16,
    scoreX=SCR_HEI + 92,
    upKey=pygame.K_UP,
    downKey=pygame.K_DOWN,
)
```

And then you don't need the `Enemy` class anymore - it uses the same code as the `Player`, but some different settings. Hope that helps!